# Heroku: Error: Missing 1 required arg: › target

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to upgrade my Heroku database following Heroku [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-heroku-postgres-databases#upgrading-with-pg-copy)

```
But i'm getting this error:
Error: Missing 1 required arg:
 ›   target
```

This is the command I'm running

```
heroku pg:copy postgres://XXX
 postgres://YYY--app APP_NAME
```

I get XXX and YYY from this command

```
heroku config -a copybot | grep URL
```

That returns

```
DATABASE_URL:                postgres://XXX
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAUVE_URL: postgres://YYY
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just solved with

```
heroku pg:copy DATABASE_URL HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAUVE --app XXX
```